# Find PHYS_OFFSET value for mkbootimg

Tags: linux, ram, kernel

As I was following the instructions from [here](http://whiteboard.ping.se/Android/Debian), I found a problem that my `/proc/config.gz` does not contain `CONFIG_PHYS_OFFSET` setting. But my `/proc/iomem` contains `40000000-5bffffff : System RAM`.

What value should I use for `--base` argument of mkbootimg? I am guessing 0x40000000, but I may be completely wrong.

Comment: Ive been told on IRC that my guess is correct. I am going to "answer my question" after checking it